# Process.StandardOutput/StandardError long running process not getting data in container

Tags: python, c#, containers, redirectstandardoutput

I am hosting a Python script in a container with the Python script started by firing off the python interpreter via Process. I have set up the ProcessStartInfo like this:

```
pyProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pyProc.StartInfo.FileName = "python3";
pyProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
pyProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
...
pyProc.Start();
...
pyProc.BeginErrorReadLine();
pyProc.BeginOutputReadLine();
...
pyProc.WaitForExit();
```

I start the process, and I have tried setting up async tasks reading from the exposed stream readers, and I have tried to implement handlers for the events exposed. The problem is that neither of the approaches yield any callbacks when I run the python script (and it has plenty of print statements and a couple of writes to standard error). Since the script is long running, I'd like to get events as they happen. Is that even possible?

My async stream readers look like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
   while (!this.cts.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
     var line = await pyProc.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync();
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
     {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
     }
   }
});
```

The event handlers look like this:

```
pyProc.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Data)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't believe this has anything to do with python.  The script could be anything, right?  Should probably remove the python tag.

Comment: I thought this would be specific to Python - I took the proverbial Write500Lines sample from MSDN and introduced a delay between writes to see if the calling process could get  the output in "real time". It seemed to work, so I must assume it is something Python does.